# OpenJPA Parent Child cascade insert issue

Tags: java, jpa, db2, openjpa

I have the following entity hierarchy:

**Parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CNTC_RLTNSHP")
public class ContactRelationship  implements Serializable { // Parent
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "O_CNTC_RLTNSHP_ID", updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer contactRelationshipID;

@Column(name = "O_WRK_ID")
private Long odsID;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "phoneContactRelationship", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = ContactRelationshipPhone.class)
private List<ContactRelationshipPhone> contactRelationshipPhones;

// ...
```

**Child**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CNTC_RLTNSHP_PH")
public class ContactRelationshipPhone  implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ContactRelationshipPhonePK id;

@Column(name = "CNTC_PH_NMBR_TXT")
private String contactPhoneNumber;

@Column(name = "PRMY_PH_INDCTR")
private String contactPrimaryPhoneIndicator;

@MapsId("contactRelationshipID")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "O_CNTC_RLTNSHP_ID", referencedColumnName = "O_CNTC_RLTNSHP_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ContactRelationship phoneContactRelationship;

public ContactRelationshipPhone() {
}

// ...
```

**Child PK**

```
@Embeddable
public class ContactRelationshipPhonePK implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "O_CNTC_RLTNSHP_ID")
private Integer contactRelationshipID;

@Column(name = "PH_TYP_CD")
private String phoneCode;

@Column(name = "PH_TYP_TXT")
private String phoneText;

public ContactRelationshipPhonePK() {
}   

// ...
```

The generated primary key is not set in child classes hence I get a SQL exception while inserting data in child tables.

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1715851 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: com.principal.scbu.ods.entity.worker.ContactRelationshipPhone@61b061b0
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:594)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:73)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1715851 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: com.principal.scbu.ods.entity.worker.ContactRelationshipPhone@61b061b0
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2352)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2189)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2087)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:2005)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1529)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:933)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:570)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1715851 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: AN UPDATE, INSERT, OR SET VALUE IS NULL, BUT THE OBJECT COLUMN O_CNTC_RLTNSHP_ID CANNOT CONTAIN NULL VALUES {prepstmnt 1218201756 INSERT INTO XXX.CNTC_RLTNSHP_PH (PH_TYP_CD, PH_TYP_TXT, CNTC_PH_NMBR_TXT, PRMY_PH_INDCTR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) [params=(null) null, (null) null, (String) E, (String) E]} [code=-407, state=23502]SQLCA OUTPUT[Errp=DSNXODM , Errd=12, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]
AN UPDATE, INSERT, OR SET VALUE IS NULL, BUT THE OBJECT COLUMN O_CNTC_RLTNSHP_ID CANNOT CONTAIN NULL VALUES
THE DESCRIBE STATEMENT DOES NOT SPECIFY A PREPARED STATEMENT
THE EXECUTE STATEMENT DOES NOT IDENTIFY A VALID PREPARED STATEMENT
FailedObject: com.principal.scbu.ods.entity.worker.ContactRelationshipPhone@61b061b0
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4991)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4957)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary.newStoreException(DB2Dictionary.java:571)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:78)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:144)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushInternal(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flush(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.flush(BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:131)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: AN UPDATE, INSERT, OR SET VALUE IS NULL, BUT THE OBJECT COLUMN O_CNTC_RLTNSHP_ID CANNOT CONTAIN NULL VALUES {prepstmnt 1218201756 INSERT INTO XXXX.CNTC_RLTNSHP_PH (PH_TYP_CD, PH_TYP_TXT, CNTC_PH_NMBR_TXT, PRMY_PH_INDCTR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) [params=(null) null, (null) null, (String) E, (String) E]} [code=-407, state=23502]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:219)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:195)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$1000(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1134)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:275)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBCStoreManager.java:1792)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:268)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:119)
    ... 19 more
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="jpa-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.principal.scbu.ods.entity.worker.ContactRelationship</class>
        <class>com.principal.scbu.ods.entity.worker.ContactRelationshipPhone</class>
        <class>com.principal.scbu.ods.entity.worker.ContactRelationshipPhonePK</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL"
                value="jdbc:db2://host:port/dbname:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="*****" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="*******" />              
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="XXX" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2" />
            <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="local" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Compatibility"
                value="StrictIdentityValues=false,QuotedNumbersInQueries=true" />
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="0" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log"
                value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults"
                value="jpa(ForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict, JoinForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict)" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrintParameters=true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant column does not even appear in the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO XXX.CNTC_RLTNSHP_PH 
      (PH_TYP_CD, PH_TYP_TXT, CNTC_PH_NMBR_TXT, PRMY_PH_INDCTR)
```

which perhaps isn't surprising given you have marked it as `insertable=false, updateable = false`.

```
@MapsId("contactRelationshipID")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "O_CNTC_RLTNSHP_ID", referencedColumnName = "O_CNTC_RLTNSHP_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ContactRelationship phoneContactRelationship;
```

Try removing these attributes.

Give your update, the remaining issue is that you are most likely not setting both side of the relationship which you must always do.

```
ContactRelationship  cr = new ContactRelationship  ();
ContactRelationshipPhone  crp = new ContactRelationshipPhone ();
cr.getContactRelationshipPhones.add(crp);
crp.setPhoneContactRelationship(cr);
```

Comment: I tried removing it still getting same error .The insert statement have changed now                                                                                                                        AN UPDATE, INSERT, OR SET VALUE IS NULL, BUT THE OBJECT COLUMN *N CANNOT CONTAIN NULL VALUES {prepstmnt 1706321332 INSERT INTO XXX.CNTC_RLTNSHP_PH (O_CNTC_RLTNSHP_ID, PH_TYP_CD, PH_TYP_TXT, CNTC_PH_NMBR_TXT, PRMY_PH_INDCTR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [params=(null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (String) E, (String) E]} [code=-407, state=23502]SQLCA OUTPUT[Errp=DSNXRIHD, Errd=-136, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]

Comment: your persitence.xml is not relevant to the question. Remove that and post the code where you construct and save the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Alan Hay provides good points, but I'd disagree that the persistence.xml file is not relevant.  Alan may be right, but it is interesting to see the settings used.  There is a lot going on in the p.xml file.  One thing I do not like is the use of "openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses".  This should be removed, please see the comments "This function is often useful for rapid prototyping but is not generally recommended for use in production." in this doc:

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/manual#openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses

It might also be interesting to see if the openjpa.Compatibility and openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults settings make a difference.  Ultimately as Alan stated your code to create/persist the entity would be of value to see here.

Comment: It worked for me after setting parent in child i.e setting ContactRelationship in ContactRelationshipPhone. Thanks Alan and Heath